# Is there a way to rewrite all of circular motions in exterior algebra?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, notation, clifford-algebra

The torque is defined as the cross product between the position vector and the applied force:
$$\tau = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}. $$

The cross product only works in 2 and 3 dimensions and the generalization of the cross product is the exterior product $ \wedge$. The cross product can be represented in the exterior form as
$$ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = - *(\vec{a} \wedge \vec{b}).  $$

Is there a good source where somebody rewrote the entirety of circular motions by only sticking to exterior algebra?

Comment: Since you have tagged this as [tag:clifford-algebra], I believe that the go-to book on classical mechanics in the geometric (clifford) algebra framework is still [Doran & Lasenby](https://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Algebra-Physicists-Chris-Doran/dp/0521715954) (Amazon link). Is that the sort of resource you are looking for?

Comment: @KyleKanos maybe, I guess. Hard to tell if you have no preview of the content, but still thanks.

Comment: Some more previews are available on the Cambridge publishers page; [this should be direct link to Ch 3](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/geometric-algebra-for-physicists/classical-mechanics/20233768C76E9E00A6F8E770A2DA229F) which covers classical mechanics, including rotational mechanics.

Comment: Kyle Kanos referenced Doran & Lasenby, which is exactly what you are looking for, but I would also like to reccommend [*May the Forque be With You!*](https://bivector.net/PGADYN.html) by Leo Dorst and Steven De Keninck. This is a unified treatment of linear and rotational motion, and is an extension/re-interpretation of [screw theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory) using a geometric/Clifford algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I think that https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.03560 has a good pedagogical explanation of this topic.

Answer (score -1):

I think its geometric algebra rather than merely exterior algebra that is the crux here; this recent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5R2sv9GCwz0&t=7s&ab_channel=Bivector) series gives a great dimension-agnostic treatment of rigid body dynamics using geometric algebra; very worth watching.

Comment: I disagree; I think that exterior algebra is really all you need and that geometric algebra just adds in a bunch of unnecessary complications.

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion; you can using an exterior product represent all contracting parts of a geometric product via dualization, so you are not wrong. Exterior and geometric are hardly different parts of mathematics really, just different dialects. That being said try writing an nd-rigid body simulator like in the link above while avoiding GA idioms, and then see if your opinion has changed at all.